# Open popup center of the pattern in kendo ui

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I have iframe in my page, in the iframe I have a button which should open window in center of my page.

```
$(function () {
        var offset = 0;
        var windowWidth = $(document).width();
        var parametrs = 'siteId=@ViewBag.siteId&widgetId=@Model.WidgetId';
        var popupWindow = $(".popupWindow").each(function () {
            var popupWindows = $(this).kendoWindow({
                iframe: true,
                width: $(document).width() - 25,
                height: 300,
                resizable: false,
                draggable: false,
                actions: ["Minimize", "Maximize", "Close"],
                visible: false,
                content: '@Url.Action("Index", "Editor")?' + parametrs,

            }).data('kendoWindow');

            var parent = $(this).parent();
            parent.css("top", parent.offset().top + offset);
            offset += parent.outerHeight();
            popupWindows.open();


        });
        $("#container").sortable();
    });
```

I use kendo ui window.

Answer (score 1):

`popupWindows.center()` will center your popup.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    var offset = 0;
    var windowWidth = $(document).width();
    var parametrs = 'siteId=@ViewBag.siteId&widgetId=@Model.WidgetId';
    var popupWindow = $(".popupWindow").each(function () {
        var popupWindows = $(this).kendoWindow({
            iframe: true,
            width: $(document).width() - 25,
            height: 300,
            resizable: false,
            draggable: false,
            actions: ["Minimize", "Maximize", "Close"],
            **open : function() { this.center(); }**
            visible: false,
            content: '@Url.Action("Index", "Editor")?' + parametrs,

        }).data('kendoWindow');

        var parent = $(this).parent();
        parent.css("top", parent.offset().top + offset);
        offset += parent.outerHeight();
        popupWindows.open();


    });
    $("#container").sortable();
});
```

Add the function for `open` which is triggered every time the popup is opened. In this function use `center()` thus placing your popup at the center of the page every time you open it.

Or you can simple use the statement `popupWindows.center()` after `popupWindows.open()` statement.